# Grafana relabel legend on Prometheus time-series bar gauge via sql lookup

Tags: sql, prometheus, grafana

I have a simple panel displaying a bar gauge from a Prometheus query:

```
sum by (obj_id) (increase(my_fancy_metric{}[$__range])) > 0
```

and the bar gauge displays as expected, similar to:

```
<uuid1> [||||||||          ] 800
<uuid2> [||||||||||||||||  ] 1600
<uuid3> [|||||             ] 400
<uuid4> [||||||||          ] 800
<uuid5> [||||||            ] 600
```

However I would like to replace all the UUID's with human-readable names which I can access in a sql table

```
select id as obj_id, name from my_table
```

---

---

---

Originally I tried to do this via Transforms hoping that there would be something that would allow me to do a lookup in the table to replace the uuid with the name (i.e. `uuid --> select name from my_table where id = {{obj_id}}` or something simple like that.

After lots of attempts I finally think perhaps I can acheive this using a `-- Mixed --` query setup and a `Merge` transform

If I add both queries and set to format as `Table` then set the Visualization to `Table` form I somewhat see the results I'm expecting

```
Time | obj_id | Value | name
-----|--------|-------|-----
<timestamp>|UUID1|200|My First Item
<timestamp>|UUID1|200|My First Item
<timestamp>|UUID1|400|My First Item
<timestamp>|UUID2|200|My Second Item
<timestamp>|UUID2|200|My Second Item
<timestamp>|UUID2|200|My Second Item
<timestamp>|UUID2|200|My Second Item
<timestamp>|UUID2|200|My Second Item
<timestamp>|UUID2|600|My Second Item
<timestamp>|UUID3|200|My Third Item
<timestamp>|UUID3|200|My Third Item
<timestamp>|UUID4|200|My Fourth Item
<timestamp>|UUID4|200|My Fourth Item
<timestamp>|UUID4|400|My Fourth Item
<timestamp>|UUID5|600|My Fifth Item
```

I was hoping then I could simply place `{{name}}`` in the Legend field, alas no.

---

---

---

**TL;DR; I'm trying to replace the legend in my grafana display from the {{obj_id}} with the matching `name` value from a lookup to a SQL table**

Comment: Since you are using bar gauge you probably only need only last metric result. Is that correct? If so, you can switch type of your Prometheus query to instant, and then use join by field Transfprmation.

Comment: Thanks, I only need the last metric so instant makes sense.

I'm using Grafana 7.4.5 so looks like Join by field is `Outer Join`
https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v7.4/panels/transformations/types-options/#join-by-field-outer-join

When I use this and join by obj_id setting both query a and b to format: table and visuallization to table I get a great looking table with the data I expect

Then when I display the bar gauge for all values I just get
Value |||||
Value |||
Value |||||||||

But hoping to display the name from the data

Comment: I'm not sure on 7.4, but on current version version, if Prometheus' query format is set to table, you join, then you organize fields to hide join key, maybe you select _All values_ in panel options, and that's all, you get your desired legend in bar gauge.